# Stack overflow error GUI programming

Tags: java, object, settext

I have a big problem i tried to solve it for days. I programmed a little program but it doesn't work.The error is Stackoverflow I already searched this website on and on again .I broke it down to the part wich doesn't works so here is the code.
This is the frame:

```
package snippet;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {   

  JButton button;
  JLabel label;
  TextEdit textEdit = new TextEdit();

    public void LetsGo() {

    setBounds(0, 0, 800, 510);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Game");
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Labels

    label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("Change Me");
    label.setBounds(30, 25, 200, 50);
    label.setVisible(true);
    add(label);

    button = new JButton();
    button.setText("I Will Change A Text");
    button.setBounds(30, 130, 200, 400);
    button.addActionListener(new Listener());;
    add(button);        
}
    public class Listener implements ActionListener {                       

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textEdit.editTheText();
        }
    }
```

And this object should edit the Text :

```
    package snippet;

public class TextEdit {
    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    public void editTheText(){
        frame.label.setText("Text was edited");
    }
}
```

So the real code is much more complex so i won't put all in one Object
Would be great if i receive some help would be very very thankful for that

Comment: The error was Stackoverflow

Comment: Please [add your error to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34730291/edit) because I see a NullPointerException, not a StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `MyFrame` in `TextEdit`, which I don't think is what you want to do because `frame.label` will be `null`.

What you really should be doing is assigning the `JFrame` inside of `Listener`.

public class Listener implements ActionListener {

```
   private JFrame frame;

   public Listener(JFrame frame) {
       this.frame = frame;
   }                      

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (this.frame.label != null) {
            this.frame.label.setText("Text was edited");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Then for the the other code, you don't have a constructor or your actual class is called `LetsGo`?

Assuming it is not called `LetsGo` and it actually is `MyFrame`, you need an actual constructor.

```
public MyFrame() {
    LetsGo();
}
```

Then in the `LetsGo` method, add the frame to the `Listener`

```
button.addActionListener(new Listener(this));
```